# HTML Script is running in JSfiddle but not on my browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, click, toggle

I'm trying to get an image to toggle on click sort of like play/pause buttons, it seems to work in JSfiddle but not on my browser. Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#infoToggler").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});​

});​

</script>

<div id="infoToggler"><img src="play.png"/>
<img src="pause.png" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you including the jquery library in your page? Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your script

Comment: Check your console. There should be something there.

Comment: I think you should put your `script` after the DOM and just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @JiangangXiong - Why? It's not necessary given the OP is using a document ready handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn I want to advice OP to make sure that the script will run after the jquery has been loaded.

Comment: @JiangangXiong - It just needs to be after the `<script>` element that includes jquery.js. (Though in the code shown jquery.js isn't included at all, which is likely the problem.) Not that putting it at the end is a bad idea, but, again, it's certainly not necessary.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yean, and that put the `script` in the end of the `<body>` is a better practice.